# $_GET is empty when the url has variables

Tags: php, variables, post, get, global-variables

I have a url that look like this `reg.php?lang=no_NO&passkey=test`and im trying to get the passkey variable, but it keeps showing up blank.

When I try `print_r($_GET);` it prints `Array ( )` ?! How can this happen?

The site look something like this

```
    <?php

        print_r($_GET); 

        include('..\libs\Smarty.class.php');
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Activate account</title>

(...html code.. )

$smarty = new Smarty;

//$smarty->force_compile = true;
$smarty->debugging = false;
$smarty->caching = false;
$smarty->cache_lifetime = 120;


// PHP gettext api
define('PROJECT_DIR', realpath('./'));

(... define gettext ... )

$passkey=$_GET['passkey'];

(...work with passkey ...)

$smarty->display('templates\site.tpl');

?>


</body>
</html>
```

thats it. I can't understand why $_GET shows up blank. It's been driving me crazy for a while now..

Comment: are you using any kind of url rewriting or is reg.php an actual file?

Comment: Are you by chance using CodeIgniter or another framework? Sometimes they stomp on the $_REQUEST variables.

Comment: @darma: even if reg.php is a real file - mod_rewrite can lost the query string if it was written improperly

Comment: @Matt Williamson: actually that does not explain why $_GET has disappeared.

Comment: @zerkms : you're right, i was especially thinking about a [QSA] that could be missing.

Comment: @zerkms: $_REQUEST includes $_POST and $_GET and I know for a fact that CodeIgniter kills them so you have to use their special functions to get at them.

Comment: "CodeIgniter kills them" -- is it true???????? why the hell do they do it? one more "cons" against CI.

Comment: @zerkms CI auto-filters all GETS as a safety measures. _POST works exactly as you would expect. You can also use the _GET if you want to, just have to explicitly enable it.

Comment: @zerkms to prevent some bad practices around them.

Comment: I ran into the same issue without a framework and mod_rewrite was enabled. It was because I was building the URL manually and I did set the hash code **before** the GET query and therefore the GET query was recognized as part of the hash string.

Comment: For people using apache, this error also happens when a folder exists in your root directory that matches the name of a rewrite path, effectively swallowing up the GET parameters.  Check for a matching folder name and rename it as a test.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I run into something that stumps me like this, I always take my script right down to basics. Try this at the very top of your script:

```
var_dump($_GET);
exit;
```

Then you can see if in fact it is getting the vars from the hook. If not, then there may be something deeper... like is PHP really running with Apache? If it works, start adding in other things until it stops again and you can start narrowing down the culprit.

Comment: hi i am getting var dump as empty array..now how to debug this...??

I have appended values in the URL

Comment: That means that nothing is coming in on the GET request. Try $_REQUEST. Are you sure you are not posting?

Answer (score 5):

Moving this into an answer from my comments above. Two reasons your GET params might be missing. Either you have mode rewrite set up that removes them or you are using a framework, such as CodeIgniter that moves them elsewhere.

In case you are using CodeIgniter you can re-enable them with `parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);`

Comment: printing out `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` might not actually be a bad place to start regardless of framework.

Comment: I would like to add that for some frameworks/CMSes the reason might be that mod_rewrite is not enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your php.ini file doesn't set `max_input_vars` to `0`. I accidentally set mine to something else so adding anything to $_GET created a PHP warning.

Answer (score 0):

i ran into a similar problem of `$_GET[]` empty. mostly because of a server issue somewhere and i had to generate my own `$GET` using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

```
//url='http://example.com/?search=john&location=london';
$get=array();
$query=mb_split("&",parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],PHP_URL_QUERY));
if(!empty($query)) foreach ($query as $qr){
    $vars=mb_split('=',$qr);
    $get[$vars[0]]=$vars[1];
}

var_dump($get['search']);
// output 'john'
```