# URL $_GET will not work

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, get

I have a problem I never had and I can't find the reason.
I moved my site to another host and now  it doesnt "read" the $_GET variables.

I have this url: http://whatever.com/path?filtro=si&provincia=Santa+Fe&localidad=Rosario
And if I call this:

```
$localidad = $_GET['localidad'];
$provincia = $_GET['provincia'];
$filtro = $_GET['filtro'];

echo $localidad;
echo "hola";
echo $provincia;
echo $filtro;
```

Nothing prints except "hola", so there is no PHP error.
Here's my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Im working on a Wordpres site, perhaps it has something to do with Permalinks or something, Im really lost. Thank you very much, I appreciate your help.

**EDIT**

I renamed my .htacces so it wont read it and the page broke, so I went to permalink settings in wordpress and set them to

```
 - Post Name    http://luminias.com/index.php/example-page/
```

And now IT WORKS, but, now this is thw url:

http://whatever.com/index.php/path/?filtro=si&provincia=Santa+Fe&localidad=Rosario

And it prints all the $_GET, but I need that "/index.php/" gone..

Comment: In wich file do you want to echoes it? What is the `/path` Where it is point?

Comment: Those are the _full contents_ of your .htaccess?  Enable PHP's error reporting/display and inspect `$_GET` with: `var_dump($_GET);`. At the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  If GET is not populated, you'll get notices about undefined array indices.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks, I did that and this came up: 
`Notice: Undefined index: localidad in E:\kunden\homepages\1\d456765835\www\Luminias\wp-content\themes\twentytwelve\puntosdeventas.php on line 44`

And this a FEW times, for every get I call in the entire file.

Comment: @lolka_bolka its a Wordpress Page made with a template in an php file. Im echoing them in that php file.

Comment: Look through your directory hierarchy to ensure that you don't have another .htaccess at a higher level, which is superceding this one and eliminating your query string.  I would also debug by renaming the .htaccess (to disable it) and see if your `$_GET` is affected.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463642/get-is-empty-when-the-url-has-variables

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski This WORKED, but please take a look at the post, I edited it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add `add_rewrite_tag` function in your function.php for all parameter :

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
        add_rewrite_tag('%localidad%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

And you can call your parameter in template using

```
$wp_query->query_vars['localidad']
```

Here is the [full documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag)

> Note that using `$_GET` on a rewritten URL will not work, even if the
>   rewrite includes the querystring variables. You must use `$wp_query`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this did not work. In my previous server worked wonderful, its a form method GET the one who rewrites the URL, I dont get why it does not work now

Comment: Why shouldnt a $_GET parameter work on a rewritten URL exactly? I updated a page earlier today that consisted of rewritten url's and still had access to $_GET parameters.