# How to get GET variable?

Tags: wordpress

I have worpdress with custom script but for my link:

```
http://mysite/script/?p=1
```

$_GET is empty, get_query_var too. How to get this variable?

Comment: Hmm I remember I already had this problem one or two times but i forgot the solution. Cache enabled? Did you try to print $_GET on add_action('init') ? Workaround is also to parse $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

Comment: This guy ran in something similar and it was a `php.ini` problem. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24845529/5970334